# Manually changing values and column name in treeview

Tags: python, tkinter

Is there any way to change/delete/update or add new value in treeview just by clicking on the cell that you want to edit?
The question is the same for column names, can I manually change column name just by clicking and writing on it?

This is the treeview code that I wrote:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

myApp = Tk()
myApp.title("tree")                         
myApp.geometry("300x400")

tree = ttk.Treeview(myApp)
tree['show'] = 'headings'

sb = ttk.Scrollbar(myApp, orient="vertical", command=tree.yview)
sb.grid(row=1,column=12,rowspan=12,sticky="NS")

tree.configure(yscrollcommand=sb.set)

tree["columns"]=("1")

tree.column("1", width=230)
tree.heading("1", text="Name")

tree.insert("","end", values=("item"))

tree.grid(row=1 ,column=0,pady=5)

myApp.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you want to achieve is possible but you cannot directly write text in a `Treeview` cell so the trick is to use `place` to display an `Entry` on top of the cell you want to edit.

So the idea is the following:

- Bind mouse click in the `Treeview` to a `edit` function.
- In this function, use `tree.identify_region(x, y)` identify on which part of the `Treeview` the click was.

  - If this is a cell, you can get the item name with `tree.identify_row(y)` and the column with `tree.identify_column(x)` and then use the `tree.bbox(item, column)` function to get the position and dimension of the `Entry`.
  - If this is a heading, it is a bit more complicated because `bbox` only works for items. We can still get the x and width of the column with `bbox`, but not y and height. So the idea is to increment y until we found the boundaries of the heading using `tree.identify_region(x, y)` to check whether we are still inside the heading (see code below).
  - If it is 'nothing', and if you are below the last item, you can display the `Entry` below the last item.
- Place the `Entry` on top of the element to edit
- Edit element text when the user hits `<Return>` and destroy the `Entry`.

Here is the code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


def edit(event):

    if tree.identify_region(event.x, event.y) == 'cell':
        # the user clicked on a cell

        def ok(event):
            """Change item value."""
            tree.set(item, column, entry.get())
            entry.destroy()

        column = tree.identify_column(event.x)  # identify column
        item = tree.identify_row(event.y)  # identify item
        x, y, width, height = tree.bbox(item, column) 
        value = tree.set(item, column)

    elif tree.identify_region(event.x, event.y) == 'heading': 
        # the user clicked on a heading

        def ok(event):
            """Change heading text."""
            tree.heading(column, text=entry.get())
            entry.destroy()

        column = tree.identify_column(event.x) # identify column
        # tree.bbox work sonly with items so we have to get the bbox of the heading differently
        x, y, width, _ = tree.bbox(tree.get_children('')[0], column) # get x and width (same as the one of any cell in the column)
        # get vertical coordinates (y1, y2)
        y2 = y
        # get bottom coordinate
        while tree.identify_region(event.x, y2) != 'heading':  
            y2 -= 1
        # get top coordinate
        y1 = y2
        while tree.identify_region(event.x, y1) == 'heading':
            y1 -= 1
        height = y2 - y1
        y = y1
        value = tree.heading(column, 'text')

    elif tree.identify_region(event.x, event.y) == 'nothing': 
        column = tree.identify_column(event.x) # identify column
        # check whether we are below the last row:
        x, y, width, height = tree.bbox(tree.get_children('')[-1], column)
        if event.y > y:

            def ok(event):
                """Change item value."""
                # create item
                item = tree.insert("", "end", values=("", ""))
                tree.set(item, column, entry.get())
                entry.destroy()

            y += height
            value = ""
        else:
            return
    else:
        return
    # display the Entry   
    entry = ttk.Entry(tree)  # create edition entry
    entry.place(x=x, y=y, width=width, height=height,
                anchor='nw')  # display entry on top of cell
    entry.insert(0, value)  # put former value in entry
    entry.bind('<FocusOut>', lambda e: entry.destroy())  
    entry.bind('<Return>', ok)  # validate with Enter
    entry.focus_set()


myApp = tk.Tk()

tree = ttk.Treeview(myApp, show='headings', columns=("1", "2"))
tree['show'] = 'headings'

tree.column("1", width=230)
tree.heading("1", text="Name")
tree.column("2", width=230)
tree.heading("2", text="Price")
for i in range(10):
    item = tree.insert("", "end", values=("item %i" % i, i))
    tree.item(item, tags=item)
tree.bind('<1>', edit)

tree.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

myApp.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks, but can I add new row in the same way?

Comment: @AleksandarBeat To add a new item, the principle is the same. I have added the case to my function.

Comment: thanks a lot, you really helped me!

One more question, is there a way to place grid inside the treeview?

Comment: @AleksandarBeat I don't understand what you mean by 'place grid inside the treeview', can you explain?

Comment: to have lines between columns and rows

Comment: @AleksandarBeat As far as I know, there is no simple way to show the grid

Comment: ok, thanks a lot my friend, you helped me a lot.
Can you tell me just where can i find some video tutorials for learning this kind of stuff? Such as keyboard controls for python tkiner?

If I want to swich between cells in my table with keybord arrows?

Comment: @AleksandarBeat I haven't used video tutorials to learn Tkinter so I cannot recommend any. I mostly use the documentation available [here](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/index.html). You can already navigate between rows in the tree with the arrow keys but I don't think it is possible to select a single cell.

Comment: ok, thanks a lot, you are great !

@j_4321

I have one more question (sorry if im borring)

What "bind" / function should I use, if I want to validate user entry just by clicking on the other cell (without clicking Enter)?

Comment: @AleksandarBeat bind the `ok` function to `<FocusOut>`(and remove the binding of `destroy` to  `<FocusOut>`)